# Point clustering only works for part of area using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the 3rd party scripts for point clustering as published by Globoserve, http://globoserve.posterous.com/ .  I followed the instructions to the letter - and just replaced the queryTask variable to point to my point features that are projected in the one of the compatible projection systems.

But the point cluster alogrithm will only cluster a section of points rather than all of my points - see image below.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I have tried this with a totally different point layer in US - and it shows a 500 point limit - the same as the pic below!

Comment: Is this making a [REST query](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/query.html)?  If so "there is a limit on the number of features included in the feature set response".  This would result in your clusterer only getting the first 1000 points.

Comment: Yes - can you change the limit?

Comment: Only by changing the config on the server AFIAK.  The workaround is to use returnIdsOnly "Clients can exploit this to get all the query conforming object IDs by specifying returnIdsOnly=true and subsequently requesting feature sets for subsets of object IDs".

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, can you formulate an answer for this along the lines of changing your config file, MaxRecordCount, for the relevant map service (found in Program Files/ArcGIS/server/user/cfg). Then I can award you the answer/points etc.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change the config file for the map service by manually editing it.  The file is found in:

**Program Files/ArcGIS/server/user/cfg**

Find the entry called

***MaxRecordCount***

and change to appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

we did it through the server-side clustering solutions and use Esri js-apis to plot the JSON outputs;
pls see the app link:

[Google Map](http://www.bdvengine.info:8080/bdvengine/BDVMap.html)